# android - foreground notification is cancelled on app removed from recent apps

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am making music player app , I start foreground service for the music playing process. but when app is removed from recent apps foreground notification is cancelled and music still plays! , which means foreground service without notification.
i have tried : `setAutoCancel(false)` and`setOnGoing(true)`
when creating `NotificationCompat.Builder` inctance and both didn't work.

my notification creation code

```
public class MediaStyleHelper {
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "2229";
public static NotificationCompat.Builder from(
        Context context, MediaSessionCompat mediaSession) {
    MediaControllerCompat controller = mediaSession.getController();
    MediaMetadataCompat mediaMetadata = controller.getMetadata();
    MediaDescriptionCompat description = mediaMetadata.getDescription();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context , CHANNEL_ID);
    builder
            .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
            .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
            .setSubText(description.getDescription())
            .setLargeIcon(description.getIconBitmap())
            .setContentIntent(controller.getSessionActivity())
            .setDeleteIntent(
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(context, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

    return builder;
}
```

}

the service in manifest:

```
<service android:name=".services.AudioPlayerService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and starting foreground code

```
private void showPlayingNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = MediaStyleHelper.from(this, mMediaSessionCompat);
    if( builder == null ) {
        return;
    }

    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, getString(R.string.pause), MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)));
    builder.setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0).setMediaSession(mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    startForeground(1,builder.build());
    //NotificationManagerCompat.from(AudioPlayerService.this).notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

note that i created notification channel using the code:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.setSound(null,null);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your service should start Sticky and if your service is START_STICKY already check your ROM, I saw some ROMs like some of Xiaomi ROMs which they close the notification when you exit app from recent and there is no way to handle it by yourself

Comment: @AliZeynali my service isn't stopped at all the problem is with the notification only. and i tried in galaxy s4 and nokia 7 plus and nexus emulator .. all have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to call `startService(Intent)` from activity. even if i called `MediaBrowserCompat.connect()` and media plays correctly , I needed to call `startService(Intent)`!
the code after this edit is:

```
public void initMediaBrowserCompat(){
    startService(new Intent(this,AudioPlayerService.class));
    mMediaBrowserCompat = new MediaBrowserCompat(this, new ComponentName(this, AudioPlayerService.class),
            mMediaBrowserCompatConnectionCallback, getIntent().getExtras());
    mMediaBrowserCompat.connect();

}
```